# How to handle errors from setTimeout in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

Simple question about `try`/`catch` for function in `setTimeout`

```
try {
    setTimeout(function () {
        throw new Error('error!');
    }, 300)
} catch (e) {
    console.log('eeee!')
    console.log(e)
}
```

Why doesn't catch block work?

What can I read about this?

P.S: the question is about possibility of handling errors like this. Don't answer about promises.

Answer (score 96):

Functions scheduled to run with `setTimeout` are executed in the main loop, outside the body of code that originated them.

To handle errors, put the `try-catch` inside the `setTimeout` handler:

```
setTimeout(function () {
  try {
    throw new Error('error!');
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
  }
}, 300)
```

If you need to access the `Error` object from block that called `setTimeout`, use [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise):

```
const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(function () {
    try {
      throw new Error('error!');
      resolve(); // if the previous line didn't always throw

    } catch (e) {
      reject(e)
    }
  }, 300)
})

promise
  .then(result => console.log("Ok " + result))
  .catch(error => console.error("Ouch " + error))
```

This example above is not the most elegant way of handling the case with a `Promise`. Instead, implement a `delay(ms)` function like this:

```
function delay(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms))
}
```

Then call

```
delay(300).then(myFunction).catch(handleError)
```

Comment: solid answer; maybe instead of "are executed in the main loop" write "are executed in the event loop (scheduled as macrotasks)", that is closer to the common JavaScript terminology (I believe; at least searching for these words yields good results for deeper details)

Answer (score 36):

You can find good explanation in this Node.js official [doc](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v7.x/docs/api/errors.html#errors_node_js_style_callbacks).

The problem is that when the callback of your `setTimeout()` function executes the `try { } catch(err) { }` block is already exited. Also notice that the callback can crash Node.js process.

However if you want to handle the errors in the callback of `setTimeout()` function, then you can listen them by using `process` global EventEmitter object

```
process.on('uncaughtException', function(err){
  console.log(err)   
})
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer (hint, hint @Andrew Kochnev) since it actually explains why and is most thorough.

Comment: you may end with corrupted nodejs process. Do not handle uncaught exceptions without killing the process. https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_warning_using_uncaughtexception_correctly

Comment: isn't try catch inside settimeout doing same thing as process.on .. but nice answer

Comment: Also try catch will give proper error stack..

Answer (score 3):

Because the catch block lexically surrounds the `setTimeout` call but that is not the function that throws.
The direct translation, is

```
setTimeout(function () {
  try {
    throw new Error('error!');
  } catch (e) {
    console.log('eeee!');
    console.log(e);
  }
}, 300);
```

Answer (score 3):

A bit strange solution, but sometimes it would be useful maybe...

```js
function globalErrorHandler(e) {
  console.warn('eeee!')
  console.warn(e);
}

const _setTimeoutOriginal = setTimeout;
setTimeout = function(callback, timeout) {
  const args = Array.from(arguments).slice(2);
  _setTimeoutOriginal(function() {
    try {
      callback.apply(this, args);
    } catch (e) {
      globalErrorHandler(e);
    }
  }, timeout);
};

setTimeout(function() {
  throw new Error('error!');
}, 300)
```

Answer (score 0):

When we have `try/catch` block, the code inside "try" block gets executed in that instant. When we have `await` syntax inside `try/catch` execution halts when the await line runs. In your code example, when `setTimeout` code gets executed, we are not in `try/catch` block anymore.

One way to handle is to use `setTimeout` from `timers/promises`. In `test.mjs` file, write this and execute with `node test.mjs`

```
import { setTimeout } from "timers/promises";

async function testing() {
  try {
    setTimeout(300);
    throw new Error("error!");
  } catch (e) {
    console.log("eeee!");
    console.log(e);
  }
}
```