# Any way to cause a promise to be rejected if it has an uncaught error?

Tags: javascript, promise, uncaughtexceptionhandler

It's easy to forget to use try/catch in an async function or otherwise fail to catch all possible errors when working with promises. This can cause an endless "await" is the Promise is never resolved nor rejected.

Is there any way (such as via a proxy or altering the promise constructor) to cause an async function or other promises to be rejected if there is an uncaught error? The following shows a generalized case. I'm looking for some way to get past the "await" (as in "p" should be rejected when the error is thrown) without fixing "badPromise".

````
async function badPromise() {
    const p = new Promise((res) => {
        delayTimer = setTimeout(() => {
            console.log('running timeout code...');
            if (1 > 0) throw new Error('This is NOT caught!'); // prevents the promise from ever resolving, but may log an error message to the console
            res();
        }, 1000);
    });
    return p;
}

(async () => {
    try {
        console.log('start async');
        await badPromise();
        console.log('Made it to the end'); // never get here
    } catch (e) {
        console.error('Caught the problem...', e); // never get here
    }
})();```
````

Comment: aren't you supposed to use the Promise's reject function (second argument after res) instead of throw?

Comment: There is no way of altering the promise without altering the promise...

Answer (score 2):

Promises already reject in the case of an uncaught *synchronous* error:

- [in a Promise constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/Promise#:%7E:text=If%20an%20error%20is%20thrown%20in%20the%20executor%2C%20the%20promise%20is%20rejected.), for synchronous (thrown) errors

  > If an error is thrown in the executor, the promise is rejected.
- [in `onFulfilled` and `onRejected` functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then#:%7E:text=throws%20an%20error%2C%20the%20promise%20returned%20by%20then%20gets%20rejected%20with%20the%20thrown%20error%20as%20its%20value.), such as in `then` and `catch`

  > If a handler function: [...] throws an error, the promise returned by `then` gets rejected with the thrown error as its value.
- [in `async` functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function#return_value)

  > Return Value: A `Promise` which will be resolved with the value returned by the async function, or rejected with an exception thrown from, or uncaught within, the async function.

Your problem here isn't that Promise doesn't handle uncaught errors, it's fundamentally because your error is *asynchronous*: As far as the Promise is concerned, its executor function is a successful little function that calls `setTimeout`. By the time your `setTimeout` handler runs and fails, it does so with its own stack that is unrelated to the Promise object or its function; nothing related to `badPromise` or `p` exists within your `setTimeout` handler other than the `res` reference the handler includes via closure. As in the question "[Handle error from setTimeout](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41431605/1426891)", the techniques for catching errors in `setTimeout` handlers all involved editing or wrapping the handler, and per the [HTML spec for timers](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/timers-and-user-prompts.html#timer-initialisation-steps) step 9.2 there is no opportunity to catch or interject an error case for the invocation of the function passed into `setTimeout`.

Other than editing `badPromise`, there's *almost* nothing you can do.

---

Alternatives:

- Modify/overwrite both the Promise constructor and the `setTimeout` method in sequence, wrapping the Promise constructor's method to save the `resolve`/`reject` parameters and then wrapping the global `setTimeout` method so to wrap the `setTimeout` handler with the `try`/`catch` that invokes the newly-saved `reject` parameter. **Due to the fragility of changing both global services, I strongly advise against any solutions like this.**
- Create a wrapper higher-order function (i.e. function that returns a function) that accepts a rejection callback and wraps the setTimeout call. This is technically an edit to `badPromise`, but it does encapsulate what's changing. It'd look something like this:

  ```js
  function rejectOnError(rej, func) {
    return (...args) => {
      try {
        return func(...args);
      } catch (e) {
        rej(e);
      }
    };
  }

  async function badPromise() {
    const p = new Promise((res, rej) => {                 // save reject
      delayTimer = setTimeout(rejectOnError(rej, () => {  // to use here
        console.log('running timeout code...');
        if (1 > 0) throw new Error('Now this is caught');
        res();
      }), 1000);
    });
    return p;
  }
    
  badPromise().catch(x => console.error(`outer: ${x}`));
  console.log('bad promise initiated');
  ```

Comment: Thank you, I truly appreciate the detailed feedback!

Answer (score 1):

The underlying issue is that timer callbacks run as top level code and the only way to detect errors in them is to listen for global error events. Here's an example of using a global handler to detect such errors, but it has issues which I'll discuss below the code:

```js
"use strict";
let delayTimer; // declare variable
async function badPromise() {
    const p = new Promise((res) => {
        let delayTimer = setTimeout(() => {  // declare variable!!!
            console.log('running timeout code...');
            if (1 > 0) throw new Error('This is NOT caught!'); // prevents the promise from ever resolving, but may log an error message to the console
            res();
        }, 1000);
    });
    return p;
}

(async () => {
    let onerror;
    let errorArgs = null;
    let pError = new Promise( (res, rej)=> {
        onerror = (...args) => rej( args); // error handler rejects pError
        window.addEventListener("error", onerror);
    })
    .catch( args => errorArgs = args);  // Catch handler resolves with error args
     
    // race between badPromise and global error

    await Promise.race( [badPromise(), pError] );
    window.removeEventListener("error", onerror);  // remove global error handler

    console.log("Made it here");
    if( errorArgs) {
        console.log(" but a global error occurred, arguments array: ", errorArgs);
    }

})();
```

**Issues**

- The code was written without caring what is passed to an global error handler added using `addEventListener` - you may get different arguments if you use `window.onerror = errorHandler`.
- The promise race can be won by any error event that bubbles up to `window` in the example. *It need not have been generated in the `badPromise()` call.*
- *If multiple calls to `badPromise` are active concurrently, trapping global errors won't tell you which `badPromise` call errored.*

Hence `badPromise` really is *bad* and needs to be handled with kid gloves. If you seriously cannot fix it you may need to ensure that you only ever have one call to it outstanding, and you are doing nothing else that might generate a global error at the same time. Whether this is possible in your case is not something I can comment on.

**Alternative**

A more generic alternative may be to start a timer before calling `badPromise` and use it to time out the pending state of the returned promise;

```
let timer;
let timeAllowed = 5000;
let timedOut = false;
let timeout = new Promise( res => timer = setTimeout(res, timeAllowed))
.then( timedOut = true);

await Promise.race( [badPromise(), timeout])
clearTimer( timer);
console.log( "timed out: %s", timedOut);
```

Comment: Even more generic: Just do not run the code in a timer if you can avoid it. (You can't when importing old JavaScript code that uses timers to run code. But otherwise you can.)

Comment: Thank you for the detailed feedback! It's a tough one, in this case fixing the promise isn't possible as the reason for my question is to help manage coding mistakes (ie, I'm trying to ensure I get more clear feedback if I create something like "badPromise" on accident).

Answer (score 0):

There may be a way to do this, but in your case I think you really want to use the `reject` function inside your Promise instead of `throw`. That's really what reject is for.

```
async function badPromise() {
    const p = new Promise((res, reject) => {
        delayTimer = setTimeout(() => {
            console.log('running timeout code...');
            if (1 > 0) {
              reject('This is NOT caught!');
              return;
            }
            res();
        }, 1000);
    });
    return p;
}

(async () => {
    try {
        console.log('start async');
        await badPromise();
        console.log('Made it to the end'); // never gets here
    } catch (e) {
        console.error('Caught the problem...', e); // should work now
    }
})();
```

Comment: Although this is good advice, the OP does say, "without fixing badPromise".

Comment: The error was made on purpose to demonstrate the question.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not an answer to what you want, but you could use a pattern like this for `setTimeout`:

```js
function testErrors() {
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve(), 1000);
  }).then(() => {
    throw Error("other bad error!");
  }).catch(err => {
    console.log("Catched", err);
  })
}
```

Comment: You actually don't understand OP's question, OP doesn't want people to fix the badPromise but try to catch the error inside it.

Comment: @ikhvjs Ah, thanks. (But please read my answer again.)